# Can a project on xcode 4 or 5 be stable on xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a iOS project developed on xcode version 4/5 using Objective-C.

In that code there are many xib's and older frameworks. I want to make that code stable.

So is it possible to make that code stable on xcode 7.3.1. version.
The app was developed for iPad(1).

The functionality is also somewhat depreciated.
So can anybody help me with this issue.

Is a way to make the code stable as i also dont know who developed the code it is 4 5 years old code.

Comment: Objective-C has not changed that much in Xcode 7, mostly they added stuff. Only the iOS SDK has changed a lot. But you should be able to build the app. Maybe some deprecated method will have to be rewritten but that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has changed so some of the methods and such may be broken. You'll have to re-write some of the app if it's broken.